# Store in dictionary/list strings with special characters from Attribute Table

Tags: arcpy, unicode

I need to store into a dictionary data from a shapefile that contains in several fields unrecognizable characters by ASCII, like in this one: "Städtebaulicher Entwicklungsbereich: Sanierungsgebiete SG 1 u. SG 2, Mkt. Floß". In the end, I have to create a report in Excel with all these attributes.

I get the data ( *stringVal* ) by using SearchCursor. This is a simplified code of how I store the data in the dictionary:

```
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(filename_path,["Category"])
for row in cursor:            
        stringVal=row[i]
        if stringVal not in d:
            d[stringVal]=1
        else:
            d[stringVal]=d[stringVal]+1
```

So my dictionary should look like this:

```
d={"Städtebaulicher Entwicklungsbereich: Sanierungsgebiete SG 1 u. SG 2, Mkt. Floß":1,"Städtebaulicher Entwicklungsbereich: Sanierunggebiet Südstadt, St. Grafenwöhr":4}
```

At this moment, it looks like this, when printing it:

```
d={u'Bayerisches Staatsministerium der Finanzen, f\xfcr Landesentwicklung und Heimat': 11}
```

I know it has to do with unicodes and UTF-8, but from what I read on the internet, I still couldn't solve it.

Comment: What is your code snippet to "get the data by using SearchCursor"?

Comment: I updated now the original post.

Comment: I think the problem is not about unicode. The print shows another text that is different from your text.I think the searchcursor reads another record or maybe another field.

Comment: The SearchCursor reads the proper value from the proper field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

In the first line of the script I kept using this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

while the correct form is:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

In the dictionary, the names still look weird but this doesn't matter, because now the script is able to read the data from the dictionary properly.

Comment: That's Great.your code works without it. Just handle unicodes in the code.It can be a challenge for you to learn using unicodes in python if you'll use unicode often

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your full code is like the below code.I don't know where you are using "i" in row[i]. But i set it to 0. It's mean i use "Category" field.

Note: when you want to print a dictionary with unicode strings, use **rep** and **decode**.The result of your print shows another words that is not about unicode

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"..\folder"
d={}
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(filename,["Category"])
for row in cursor:
        stringVal=row[0]
        if stringVal not in d:
            d[stringVal]=1
        else:
            d[stringVal]=d[stringVal]+1

print repr(d).decode("unicode-escape")
```